# Combine 2 MouseAreas on GridView

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, qtquick2

I have code like this:

```
GridView {
    // ... declarations ...
    model: theModel
    delegate: MouseArea {
        id: cellMouseArea
        onClicked: // open the cell
    }
    MouseArea {
        id: gridViewMouseArea
        // here process horizontal mouse press/release actions
    }
}
```

with a `MouseArea` defined in each delegate and an overall `MouseArea` covering my `GridView`.  In the `cellMouseArea` I want to perform an open item action whereas in the `gridViewMouseArea` I want to implement `mouseX` handle to open/close a sidebar. However, the two `MouseArea`s do not work together. How can I carry it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit [`propagateComposedEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#propagateComposedEvents-prop):

> **If propagateComposedEvents is set to true, then composed events will
>   be automatically propagated to other MouseAreas in the same location
>   in the scene**. Each event is propagated to the next enabled MouseArea
>   beneath it in the stacking order, propagating down this visual
>   hierarchy until a MouseArea accepts the event. Unlike pressed events,
>   composed events will not be automatically accepted if no handler is
>   present.

You can set the property to true on the `GridView` `MouseArea`. In this way click events are propagated to the `MouseArea`s in the delegates whereas the outer `MouseArea` can implement other behaviours such as drag or hoven.

Here is an example in which outer `MouseArea` defines `drag` property to slide in/out a `Rectangle` ( simulating your sidebar) and thanks to the `propagateComposedEvents` clicks are managed by the single delegates.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 300; height: 400
    color: "white"

    Component {
        id: appDelegate

        Item {
            width: 100; height: 100

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent

                onClicked: {
                    parent.GridView.view.currentIndex = index
                    console.info("Index clicked: " + index)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: appHighlight
        Rectangle { width: 80; height: 80; color: "lightsteelblue" }
    }

    GridView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 100; cellHeight: 100
        highlight: appHighlight
        focus: true
        model: 12
        delegate: appDelegate

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            z:1
            propagateComposedEvents: true   // the key property!
            drag.target: dragged
            drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
            drag.minimumX: - parent.width
            drag.maximumX: parent.width  / 2
            onMouseXChanged: console.info(mouseX)
        }
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: dragged
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "steelblue"
        x: -parent.width
    }
}
```